# How to retrieve data in parse from 2 different tables android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi i try to retrieve data from 2 different tables in android using parse but with no success. I want to retrieve "titolo" from "Luoghi" table for all my "imageFile" in Photos table. This is my
[databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dda93.jpg) and this is my code

```
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Photos");

           query.include("luogoPointer");

            listaEventiParse = query.find();

            for (ParseObject country : listaEventiParse) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("imageFile");


                ParseObject luoghi= country.getParseObject("luogoPointer");

                ListaEventiItem map = new ListaEventiItem();
                map.setImmagine(image.getUrl());
                map.setId(luoghi.getString("titolo"));
                list.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i got  `java.lang.NullPointerException` on luoghi.getString("titolo").
what i am missing?

Comment: you can achieve by promise at cloud side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You included `luogoPointer` in your query but many entries in your Photos table for this pointer is blank. When you get Photos result then you got null pointer for many records and calling `getString()` on this null pointer, that's why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

Include one more condition in your query to select only that record which contain  `luogoPointer`.

> query.whereExists("luogoPointer");

Now your query is like this :

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Photos");

       query.include("luogoPointer");
       query.whereExists("luogoPointer");

       listaEventiParse = query.find();
```

Comment: @EricTondelli its my pleasure. Please check answer as correct answer if it fullfill your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including only the pointer to include the field (or fields) you want to retrieve before the `.find()` call:

`query.include("luogoPointer.titolo");`

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but it's not working i received this error: field titolo cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object

Comment: Yes sorry, now I realized that the notation I suggested is intended to nest calls to objects, not to fields. It is not the purpose you want to achieve.

Comment: However, I think the error you are getting is due to the fact that you don't have the `luogoPointer` entry loaded. Probably what you have in your `luogi` ParseObject is only its objectId. Let me see if I can recall what you are missing.